# How to get docker container ID within Docker?

Tags: docker

I am trying to follow the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427299/4896087) in order to run a Jupyter Notebook that's not part of a prebuilt Docker container.

In order to get the contain id, I did this in Docker Quickstart Terminal when the notebook server is terminated with Ctrl + C (no response when the notebook server is running), I got

```
$ docker ps -lq
0a8f14a15b4f
```

Then I did this

```
$ docker exec -it 0a8f14a15b4f bash
Error response from daemon: Container 0a8f14a15b4f357352f3c40b6d449e1d9150a0ce79
5fd81c09c00e978ea86163 is not running
```

So, what is going on? How am I supposed to get the container id so that I can do something like below?

```
docker exec -it [container-id] bash
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the container is terminated, just do this to get the container id:

```
$ docker ps -a
```

Answer (score 1):

[`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) will only work on a running container and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> will generally stop/kill a container.

A container can be run [detached](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/detached--d), the command then prints the new container ID to stdout.

```
cid=$(docker run --detach <image>)
docker exec -ti $cid bash
```

If you still want to see the container output, use `docker logs $cid`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Matt! So am I supposed to enter the above two lines separately in the Docker Quickstart Terminal after using Ctrl+C to terminate the current container? After doing this, I got error message:"bash: command substitution: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `)' bash: command substitution: line 19: `docker run --detach <image>)'".

Comment: You need to replace `<image>` with the image you are trying to run.  The bit in between `$(` and `)` should be whatever your `docker run` command is but with `-d` or `--detach` included.

Answer (score 1):

You can get container id inside a container using a python console running inside the particular container. Basically container id is nothing but a socket hostname. You can obtain the same by following.

```
import socket; print(socket.gethostname())
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to the container using [`--name`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/name---name)
`docker run -d --name containername`

And then use the name
`docker exec -it containername bash`

Don't forget to run it with `-d` key or to run commands in the different terminals

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Valentin! I currently start the container using "docker start -ai tensorflow-udacity". So maybe I need to do this "docker exec -it tensorflow-udacity bash", but I got error message "Error response from daemon: Container 0a8f14a15b4f357352f3c40b6d449e1d9150a0ce79
5fd81c09c00e978ea86163 is not running".